# Numpy operate over 2D array to produce 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have generated a numpy array of `(x, y)` values as a `N x N` grid.

```
grid = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 50), np.linspace(0, 1, 50))[0]
grid.shape  // (50, 50, 1)
```

I have a function that takes two parameters and returns 3 values.
i.e. `(x, y) -> (a, b, c)`

How to I apply the function over the 2d numpy array to get a 3d numpy array?

Comment: It's unclear to me what an array of `(x, y)` values looks like on an `N x N` grid... Is this to imply that you have a 2D array of tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function really takes two parameters you probably want to map not 2d to 3d, but rather 2xMxN to 3xMxN. For this change your first line to something like

```
gridx, gridy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 50), np.linspace(0, 1, 50))
```

or even use the more economical `ix_` which has the advantage of not swapping axes

```
gridy, gridx = np.ix_(np.linspace(0, 1, 50), np.linspace(0, 1, 50))
```

If your function `f` does not handle array arguments then as @Jacques Gaudin points out `np.vectorize` is probably what you want. Be warned that `vectorize` is primarily a convenience function it doesn't make things faster. It does useful things like broadcasting which is why using `ix_` actually works

```
f_wrapped = np.vectorize(f)
result = f_wrapped(gridy, gridx)
```

Note that `result` in your case is a 3-tuple of 50 x 50 arrays, i.e. is grouped by output. This is convenient if you want to chain vectorized functions. If you want all in one big array just convert `result` to `array` and optionally use `transpose` to rearrange axes, e.g.

```
 triplets_last = np.array(result).transpose((1, 2, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are after the `np.vectorize` decorator. By using it you can apply a function over a `meshgrid`. Your function should take only one parameter though as you do not pass the coordinates but the value at the coordinates (unless the values are tulpes with two elements).

```
import numpy as np

grid = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 5), np.linspace(0, 1, 5))[0]

@np.vectorize
def func(a):
    return (a, a**.5, a**2)

res = np.array(list(func(grid)))
print(res.shape)
print(res)
```